# Remove Google project with OAuth client ID in google and add keystore SHA-1 in Firebase project - does it conflict with google sign in?

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, oauth

To better understand my confusion, let's suppose

> Package name: X,
>   Keystore SHA-1: Y

I already have a Google project with OAuth 2.0 client ID (Type: Android) - which has package name = X and SHA-1 = Y - added.

I have a Firebase project for my android app with package name = X (already published in play store, and uses google sign-in).

Now, I can't add SHA-1 = Y, in this firebase project since the combination X & Y has to be unique (the combination already exists in above Google project's OAuth 2.0 client ID).

What I can do is delete OAuth client ID in above Google project and then add SHA-1 fingerprint in Firebase project. My question is, will it cause any issues with google sign-in, in the already published app in play store?